# How do I keep my chocolate ganache in the right consistency?

Tags: temperature, consistency, ganache

I made a chocolate ganache and after a few hours in the fridge it was in the perfect consistency. I left it out of the fridge so it would be room temperature, and an hour later it became much harder. I tried putting it back in the fridge but it didn't help. I need to use the ganache on a cake in 12 hours. How do I get the ganache back to the right consistency?

Comment: I would expect ganache to harden/thicken in the fridge and loosen up at room temp, not the opposite...

Comment: I'm confused like mbjb ... I would expect it to harden when colder ... so I'd try warming it slightly.  Either placing it over a double boiler, or on a heating pad for a while, etc.

Comment: @Joe I just tried warming it and it worked. Thanks! Also I was a bit confused when it hardened.