# Can I add more cream to my thick and ready ganache?

Tags: cream, ganache

The answer to this question might also answer [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/114470/how-do-i-keep-my-chocolate-ganache-in-the-right-consistency).

I made ganache and it's ready, but to thick to work with (I probably messed up the chocolate-cream ratio). Can I add more cream to it if it's already ready? If yes, can the cream be warmed up before mixing it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can try adding more cream in without hurting anything. However, when cooled it may not mix in very effectively, depending on how thick it already is. If you have trouble you just need to heat it up a bit and it will mix in no problem.

Of course, heating may be a better option than adding cream in making it more workable. If you add cream it will be easier to work with when cold but runnier, if you shape it when warm and it cools it stays where you put it better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just warm everything up gently over a double boiler or in the microwave and mix thoroughly.